# Has the postgres sorting order changed between versions 11.5 and 13

Tags: postgresql

Doing a simple query to a postgres v 11.5 database yields the following results

`sql select * from table order by name.;`

```
[2021-03-09 13:27:49] testing.INFO: Hall, Hunter and Allen;;;;Hall PLC;;;;Miller, Lloyd and
```

However doing the same query on the newer version 13 produces

```
Hall PLC;;;;;;Hall, Hunter and Allen;;;;;;Miller, Lloyd and Bailey
```

I can't explain this other than what result i'm given and I can't find any more information on this matter.

Can anyone point out the change thats effected the output?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes

Answer (score 2):

The sorting order for strings in PostgreSQL depends on the collation used.

This collation is taken either from the operating system C library or from the ICU library; if you didn't specify anything, it is the C library.

So if your sorting order changed, that means that your C library changed. There is no direct connection to PostgreSQL.

Note that when you upgrade the operating system C library, you should reindex all indexes on string columns to avoid data corruption.